# Minor breaks do not show when using scale_x_reverse

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I can't get the `minor_breaks` argument to do anything when I use the convenience function `scale_x_reverse`

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(10,20,40,90,300),y=c(1,2,7,2,7)) #define data frame

# scale_x_continuous uses minor_breaks just like it should
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_line() +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(10,50,100,150,200,250,300), minor_breaks=10:300)

# scale_x_reverse seems to ignore the minor_breaks option
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_line() + 
    scale_x_reverse(breaks=c(10,50,100,150,200,250,300), minor_breaks=10:300)
```

Is there any way that I can reverse the X axis but still be able to customise the minor breaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This smells like a bug to me. `scale_x_reverse` is simply a wrapper for `scale_x_continuous` with `trans = reverse_trans()`. Now, `reverse_trans` does its work by simply defining a function that reverses the sign of each value: `function(x) -x`.

So on a hunch, I tried this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    scale_x_reverse(breaks=c(10,50,100,150,200,250,300), 
                    minor_breaks= -c(25,75,125))
```

Probably an easy fix. You might consider filing a bug report on github.